Separating Data Based on Observation and Quarter
I have a data frame that has the number of quarters since graduating college (obs) with 0 being the graduation quarter, the mean wage, and the season of the observation. The data is similar to the first code below. I would like to separate the data into four separate data frames but have values that follow the obs and season, such as the second piece of code below. I have tried using grepl() to parse the data, but it was too slow.
obs | season | wage
 0    spring   1000
 0    summer   1250
 0    fall     500
 0    winter   2000
 1    spring   700
 1    summer   1200
 1    fall     3000
 1    winter   500

obs | season | wage
 0    spring   1000
 1    summer   1200


It sounds like you want four cohorts, based on the combination of the obs number and the implied season they began. We can do this by making season a factor (so it has a defined ordering), and relating that to obs with the %% modulo operator.
Here, "spring" is the first level of the season factor, so as.numeric(season) will be 1 for "spring" rows. I wanted the first cohort to be labeled 1 instead of 0, so I subtract one before the %% and add one afterwards to get that. Thus, Spring/0 and Summer/1 are put into cohort 1.
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  mutate(season = factor(season, levels = c("spring", "summer", "fall", "winter"))) |>
  mutate(cohort = (as.numeric(season) - obs - 1) %% 4 + 1) |>
  group_by(cohort) |>
  group_split()


---

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               obs = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
            season = c("spring","summer","fall",
                       "winter","spring","summer","fall","winter"),
              wage = c(1000L, 1250L, 500L, 2000L, 700L, 1200L, 3000L, 500L)
)

This results in a list of four data frames. (Keeping data that might be analyzed the same way in a list is generally better than putting it into free-floating data frames, since you can operate on the list, instead of creating more work and room for error where you track each of the data frames.)
>[4]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
    obs season  wage cohort
  <int> <fct>  <int>  <dbl>
1     0 spring  1000      1
2     1 summer  1200      1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
    obs season  wage cohort
  <int> <fct>  <int>  <dbl>
1     0 summer  1250      2
2     1 fall    3000      2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
    obs season  wage cohort
  <int> <fct>  <int>  <dbl>
1     0 fall     500      3
2     1 winter   500      3

[[4]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
    obs season  wage cohort
  <int> <fct>  <int>  <dbl>
1     0 winter  2000      4
2     1 spring   700      4

